# Redirect back to chrome extension page from external page hangs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auth0, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to redirect back to my chrome extension page from Auth0 login. However, it hangs. I have checked the network tab of the debugger and apparently it gets stuck loading the extension page (network request shows 0 bytes). The page is already in web_accessible_resources (when I take it out of that array it is blocked as expected). What is wrong? This is the first time I have encountered this issue and I have used identical code in other apps with no problems.

This is the code (using Quasar framework):

```
this.webAuth.authorize({
            scope:'openid profile email app_metadata user_metadata client_metadata',
            audience:env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
            responseType:'token id_token',
            redirectUri:Platform.is.bex?chrome.runtime.getURL('www/index.html'):Platform.is.electron?process.env.APP_URL.replace(/\\/g,'/'):process.env.BASE_URL,
            state:window.btoa(JSON.stringify(this.state))
        })
```